# class-validator validate nested object based on parent properties

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, class-validator

Is there a way to have a field in a child object validated based on properties of the parent. The following objects represent the structure we are trying to valid. For example in the following structure only first.name is not required when id and dateOfBirth (dob) are defined?

```
@InputType()
export class GetEligibilityArgs {       
  @Field((type) => NameInput)
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => NameInput)
  name: NameInput;
 
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @ValidateIf((o: GetEligibilityArgs) => {
    return !(o.name?.first && o.name?.last && o.dateOfBirth);
  })
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'id is required' })
  id?: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @ValidateIf((o: GetEligibilityArgs) => {   // <-- not sure if this is the correct way to do this
    return !(o.id && o.name?.first && o.name?.last);
  })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  dateOfBirth?: string;
}
```

Nested Object

```
@InputType()
export class NameInput {
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  first?: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  last?: string;
}
```

Valid Inputs

- id, name.first, name.last
- id, name.first, dob
- id, name.last, dob
- name.first, name.last, dob

all else would be considered invalid

Comment: Are custom validator or validation groups applicable here? I am thinking about custom validator either on the whole object or just on the name field. Another option is to use 4 validation groups for the 4 valid cases

Comment: @Nikolay thanks, I am new to class-validator, I will do some googling on those as options. If you have a link to an example of any of what you mentioned that would be great

Comment: Implementing the validation groups is a bit tricky, it depends if you are using [global validation pipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#auto-validation) or not, because then you will not be able to apply validation groups on a Controller level - see [this issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2390)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with, please let me know if there would be a better way.

Custom Validator Constraint

```
@ValidatorConstraint()
export class GetEligibilityCriteriaConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  validate(
    { id, name, dateOfBirth }: GetEligibilityArgs,
    validationArguments: ValidationArguments,
  ) {
    if (id && name?.first && name?.last) {
      return true;
    }
    if (id && name?.first && dateOfBirth) {
      return true;
    }
    if (id && name?.last && dateOfBirth) {
      return true;
    }
    if (name?.first && name?.last && dateOfBirth) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
    return 'Eligibility requires 3 of the following 4 fields (id, name.first, name.last, dateOfBirth';
  }
}
```

Eligibility Criteria Wrapper Class use to validate object

```
@ArgsType()
export class GetEligibilityCriteria {
  @Field((type) => GetEligibilityArgs)
  @Validate(GetEligibilityCriteriaConstraint)
  @Type(() => GetEligibilityArgs)
  @ValidateNested()
  criteria: GetEligibilityArgs;
}
```

This is then used in a resolver query like so

```
 @Query((returns) => Eligibility)
  eligibility(@Args() { criteria }: GetEligibilityCriteria) {
    // performs some mapping and calls service 
  }
```

Standard validator constrains are applied on the GetEligibilityArgs class